# How did Sharp get Teia's papers?

Tags: lightbringer

In the third book of the [Lightbringer](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12652457-the-broken-eye) Series, Murder Sharp turns up with Teia's papers.

How did he get them ? I thought Andross Guile had given them to Kip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kip won her manumission papers from Andross Guile in a game of chance but Guile seem to have managed to get them back when Kip jumped overboard (presumably they were in his personal effects that were left on board).

Commander Ironfist says that he promised Kip that he would hand her papers in to the Magistrate but he never seems to have been able to get them off Andross Guile which means that **Guile gave them to Murder Sharp**, even though they don't really belong to him any more.

Sharp tells Teia that if she presses the issue (e.g. if she goes to the authorities to claim that she's legally the property of Ironfist, not Guile) that he'll be ruined:

> Think not just about the fallout for you if you tell someone. Consider
>   what happens to Commander Ironfist if he takes up your cause. **Perhaps
>   it would go well if I were to give your papers to any ordinary
>   slaveholder. But if you pit Commander Ironfist against Andross Guile?
>   Who do you think would win in that kind of fight? Ironfist is a good
>   man, and he’ll go to his destruction for you, if you tell him.”**

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't realize that Kip would have left all his worldly possessions onboard.

Comment: @Gaius - He left his spectacles, despite being practically blind without them.

Comment: Didn't Zymun steal those when he was washed ashore?

Comment: @Gaius - I'm not sure - Teia seems to think not "*After how much Kip had drafted the day before, he’d be lightsick even if he wasn’t otherwise injured.* **He’d even left his spectacles case in his bunk. He’d be helpless.**"

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR; The papers are still in Kip/Teia's room when they leave for Ru, and Murder Sharp steals them.**

Kip won them from Andross Guile in a game of Nine Kings in *The Blinding Knife*.  When Kip then tries to get Teia to register the papers, freeing her, she refuses:

> "Hold on, before we do all that, I want you to take your papers. You keep on avoiding this. Look, all you have to do is sign them and we can take them to be registered tomorrow.
>
> "Kip, don't be an idiot."

They then decide to wait until it is time for Blackguard vows, so they can split the money the Blackguard will pay for Teia's contract.

Later, when sailing to Ru, Kip asks Commander Ironfist to take care of it if anything happens to Kip:

> The commander moved to address everyone, but Kip interjected, "Sir?
>   Um, I know that after we were inducted, there wasn't really time to
>   file papers and everything. I wanted to-I'm technically, or was
>   technically, I guess? Teia's owner, anyway."
>
> "Are you worried about your payout? Now?"
>
> "No, sir!" I mean, if I die, sir, I want Teia to
>   get it all." [...]
>
> The commander looked at Kip for a long moment, then
>   nodded.  It would be taken care of.

Further, in *The Broken Eye* Ironfist says:

> Kip-Breaker-asked me to make sure your manumission papers go through.  And I will. You know you're one of the best inductees. You know the Blackguard is hurting for good people. But it's your choice. When I was your age, I took an oath because I was expected to, not because I wanted to or thought it was right. I won't do that to you, Teia.

The implication is that the papers are still in Kip's room, waiting to be filed.  Then, later, Teia is on her way to Kip's (and hers) room to get the papers and file them:

> Staying on the lift when the inductees got out, Teia left instead at the level of Kip's room. The clerks had been too busy in the days immediately before the fleet left to do any normal business. That had meant Teia and Kip couldn't file her paperwork.
>
> [...]
>
> The key turned easily in the lock, and Teia opened the door and stepped inside quickly.

This is when we meet Sharp, who has gone to the room to grab her papers and wait for her.